# Is there a way to iterate over an Object based upon the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this array ["12345678", "87654321"]
And I want to inject each index into an object in the itemId category and loop over the object again placing the second index into another itemId category.

```
var myArray = ["12345678", "87654321", "12345678"]
var idArray =[]
   var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    for (var i =0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        let idElement = myArray[i]
        idArray.push(idElement);
        console.log(idElement);

   let multipleitems = {
        Request: {
            Details: {
                id: idArray,
                amount: 1
            },
        }
    };
```

Gives me this output

```
Request: {Details: {Id: ["12345678", "12345678", "12345678" ], amount: 1}}
```

Is it possible to iterate over "details however many times based upon how many indexes are in myArray to get this output

```
{"Request":{"Details":[{"Id":"12345678","amount":1},{"itemId":"87654321","amount":1},{"Id":"12345678","amount":1}]}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very basic [array map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation. You return a new object every iteration and map() itself returns a new array

```js
var myArray = ["12345678", "87654321", "12345678"];

let multipleitems = {
  Request: {
    Details: myArray.map(id => ({id, amount:1}) )
  }
};

console.log(multipleitems)
```